# why difference in string length?

Tags: python, json, string, put

Why I get different string length?
try to type in online python compiler this code:

```
XivelyID=2
XivelyCV=3

PUTjsonBODY='{  "version": "1.0.0", \r\n\
"datastreams" : [ { \r\n\
    "id"" : "%s", \r\n\
    "current_value"" : "%s" } ]\r\n\
}\r\n'

print PUTjsonBODY %(XivelyID,XivelyCV)
print len(PUTjsonBODY)
print

XivelyID=8
XivelyCV=9

PUTjsonBODY='{  "version": "1.0.0", \r\n\
"datastreams" : [ { \r\n\
       "id"" : "%s", \r\n\
        "current_value"" : "%s" } ]\r\n\
}\r\n'%(XivelyID,XivelyCV)

print PUTjsonBODY 
print len(PUTjsonBODY)
```

1st print len(PUTjsonBODY) is 116

2nd print len(PUTjsonBODY) is 114

why?

p.s.
try enter code and run online here:

http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php

p.s.2
if above and bottom text are totaly exact above result is allways 2 more then bottom!
Why?

Answer (score 3):

The string in the first `len()` has `%s` in it, twice.

The string in the second `len()` has `8` and `9`.

`8` and `9` are two characters shorter than `%s` and `%s`.

If you want an accurate comparison, change the first `len()` to:

```
print len(PUTjsonBODY %(XivelyID,XivelyCV))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty obvious:  the first time, you don't change the value of the string `PUTjsonBODY`.  You substitute values into it, but that creates a **new** string object.  `PUTjsonBODY` remains unchanged.

The second time, you substitute values into it **before** assigning to `PUTjsonBODY`.  Different strings, different lengths.  Specifically, the first instance of `%s` in the first string is `8` in the second string, and the second instance of `%s` in the first string is `9` in the second string.  You've replaced 4 characters with 2 characters, hence the difference of 4-2 = 2 in their lengths.